# Converting Excel line breaks to vbCrLf?

Tags: vba, excel

My columns have line breaks, but how can I convert these to `vbCrLf` when reading with `Range("A" & r).Value`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. vbcrlf is a constant that is equal to "\x0A\x0D", ie. a CRLF.

Comment: @Matthew: Fixed the question, it seems the OP used "crlf" as synonym for "line break".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel cell line breaks are represended by `vbLf`, **not** `vbCrLf`.

You can replace the line breaks manually:

```
Dim CellValue As String

CellValue = Replace(Range("A" & r).Value, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

That replaces all Excel line breaks with standard Windows line breaks.

Comment: Did you assign the return value? I updated my example to include a variable to assign to.